# Show notice bar only on mobile website

Tags: jquery

I am building a website on wordpress. I need to add a notice bar similar to the one here: https://onur-durak.squarespace.com/menu/ ( visible only on mobile ) See: 
http://prntscr.com/e5psla

it needs to show only on mobile and hide when the user scroll. Can anyone help with this?

I am total n00b at js.

Thanks

Comment: do you want it done for you?

Comment: Here's a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser#11381730

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for the tips.